# In the proof for the Basis Representation Theorem, how does the range of the coefficients fit into the picture?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To my understanding, the Basis Representation Theorem says that for any integer base $b > 1$, any integer $n > 0$ can be written as:

$$
n = \sum_{k=0}^{s} c_kb^k
$$

where $c_k \in \{0,1,...,b-1\}$.

In [this proof of the Basis Representation Theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Basis_Representation_Theorem), how does the statement that $c_k \in \{0,1,...,b-1\}$ fit into the picture?

I ask because I am trying to prove that, for the case of $b = 3$, $n$ can be written as either:

$$
n = \sum_{k=0}^{s} c_k3^k
$$

where $c_k \in \{0,1,2\}$, or

$$
n = \sum_{k=0}^{s} d_k3^k
$$

where $d_k \in \{-1,0,1\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limitation of the coefficients to the set $\{0,1,\dots,b-1\}$ is used when it’s shown that if $$n=r_kb^k+r_{k-1}b^{k-1}+\ldots+r_tb^t$$ with $r_k\ne 0\ne r_t$, then

$$n-1=r_kb^k+r_{k-1}b^{k-1}+\ldots+(r_t-1)b^t+\sum_{j=0}^{t-1}(b-1)b^j\;:$$

this wouldn’t be a valid representation of $n-1$ if $b-1$ were not in the set of possible coefficients.

For the balanced ternary system with coefficients in $\{-1,0,1\}$ I’d be inclined to start from scratch rather than to try to deduce a representation theorem from the usual one. Start with uniqueness. Suppose that $n\in\Bbb Z$ has two balanced ternary representations, say

$$n=\sum_{k=0}^rc_k3^k=\sum_{k=0}^sd_k3^k\;,$$

where $r\le s$ and all $c_k,d_k\in\{-1,0,1\}$; then if we let $c_k=0$ for $r<k\le s$ we can write

$$\sum_{k=0}^s(d_k-c_k)3^k=0\;.$$

The coefficients $d_k-c_k$ are all in the set $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$.

> **Lemma.** If $a_k\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$ for $k=0,\dots,t$ and $a_t\ne0$, then $\sum_{k=0}^ta_k3^k\ne0$.
>
> **Proof.** Without loss of generality assume that $a_t>0$. (Otherwise just multiply everything by $-1$.) Then $$\sum_{k=0}^ta_k3^k\ge 3^t-2\sum_{k=0}^{t-1}3^k=3^t-2\frac{3^t-1}{3-1}=3^t-\left(3^t-1\right)=1\;.\qquad\qquad\dashv$$

It follows from the lemma that the coefficients $d_k-c_k$ are all $0$ and hence that the two representations of $n$ are identical.

To show that each $n\in\Bbb Z$ has at least one balanced ternary representation, it suffices to show that each positive integer has one: clearly if $n=\sum_{k=0}^rc_k3^k$, then $-n=\sum_{k=0}^r(-c_k)3^k$. Suppose, then, that there is at least one positive integer with no balanced ternary representation, and let $n$ be the smallest such integer. Clearly $n>1$, so by hypothesis there are a non-negative integer $r$ and $c_k\in\{-1,0,1\}$ for $k=0,\dots,r$ such that $n-1=\sum_{k=0}^rc_k3^k$. If $c_0\ne 1$, $$n=(c_0+1)+\sum_{k=1}^rc_k3^k$$ is a valid representation of $n$, so we must have $c_0=1$. If some $c_k\ne 1$, let $s$ be minimal such that $c_s\ne1$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
n&=\sum_{k=s+1}^rc_k3^k+c_s3^s+\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}3^k+1\\
&=\sum_{k=s+1}^rc_k3^k+c_s3^s+\frac{3^s-1}{3-1}+1\\
&=\sum_{k=s+1}^rc_k3^k+c_s3^s+\frac{3^s+1}2\\
&=\sum_{k=s+1}^rc_k3^k+c_s3^s+\left(3^s-\frac{3^s-1}2\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=s+1}^rc_k3^k+c_s3^s+(c_s+1)3^s-\sum_{k=0}^{s-1}3^k\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now $c_s\ne 1$, so $c_s+1\in\{-1,0,1\}$, Thus, if we let $d_k=-1$ for $k=0,\dots,s-1$, $d_s=c_s+1$, and $d_k=c_k$ for $k=s+1,\dots,r$, $$n=\sum_{k=0}^rd_k3^k$$ is a valid balanced ternary representation of $n$. This contradiction shows that every positive integer has a balanced ternary representation and hence that every integer has one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the $-1$ as digit is not usual. Thus, you would like to see $5$ as with digits '1(-1)(-1)' (meaning $9-3-1$)?

Anyway, it seems that with your $d_k$ every integer can be uniquely written.

Comment: The system with digits $-1,0,1$ is known as [balanced ternary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary).